# Track Progress of API-Call

Tags: c#, angularjs, progress-bar

I have a C#-Api-Function which takes severall minutes to execute and I want to report the progress to the User (if he stays on the page).

The Website runs with angularjs.

I could start the c#-function asynch but how can I report my progress repeatedly instead of just once?

Comment: Is it maybe possible to save progress to a variable from where another function can retrieve it?

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways to skin a cat, but one that comes into mind:

During your long running method, log progress to a database *(or a static variable if you're feeling naughty)*. Then have another API handler which would query the database for progress and return it. On the client-side, set up a timer which would query your progress handler, and update the model.

Also, you **shouldn't** have methods that take so long to return in a web API. Consider moving the logic to a windows service, or at least make the request handler asynchronous.

Comment: I'm using a global variable to try this out, bit it seems like this variable has always the same value. It isnt synchronised between two calls to the API even from the same client.